# Laravel validate unique depend on another field

Tags: laravel-9, php-8.1

I have the ordinary unique validation

```
            'bank_program_id' => [
                'required',
                'integer',
                'exists:bank_programs,id',
                Rule::unique('bank_program_country', 'bank_program_id')
                    ->where('country', $this->input('country')),
            ],
```

The business logic says there can be one unique combination `bank_program_id` + `country`

This validation works well inside form request but I wanna test the validation request and use such code:

`$validator = Validator::make($data, $request->rules());`
and the validation rule does not prevent duplicates.
Please suggest how to adapt  this code, thx in advance

Comment: Not really clear what issue you are stuck at. Could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: The main goal is create `unique` validation for combination of several fields. I've done it via `->where('country', $this->input('country'))` but I can't test it, cause validator does not know about `input`